# Are concurrent non-atomic writes to never-read memory safe?

Tags: language-agnostic, atomic

*Note: not a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59647899/2693146) question.*

Provided a region of memory is never read, when are concurrent non-atomic writes safe to it? This is language-agnostic and mostly related to CPU architectural constraints.

> The idea is for dropping bytes in non-seekable objects like TCP socket in a multi-threaded app, but in cases where BPF drop filters aren't viable.

- Are such writes okay at byte resolution? I do currently have non-mission-critical code in the wild assuming this (by doing concurrent `read` syscalls to it to sinkhole all received data entirely) and haven't had issues *so far*.
- Do the writes have to be limited to their own cache lines? One core could write and the other read and they could run into consensus issues. However, I'd *think* this would only impact the (never-read) memory region?
- Do the writes have to be limited to their own (usually 4 KiB) pages? I could see TLB issues in a few cases if it assumes unsyncronized instruction means no TLB synchronization is needed at all, though this is admittedly *very* unlikely (most of that same synchronization is needed just to handle concurrent requests with different addresses correctly).
- Is it just never safe at all in general?

Comment: Or in other words, if a tree falls in a forest and no one is around to hear it, does it make a sound?

Comment: I don't really understand your explanation of why you want to do this.  Can you explain your application more fully?  If you're writing bytes that are literally never going to be read, then what is the point?

Comment: Note that on typical modern CPU architectures, aligned load and store instructions of word size or smaller are always atomic.  This includes in particular all single-byte loads and stores.  But this promise does not carry over to higher-level languages: for instance, a C compiler may compile `uint_t *p = ... ; *p = 1;` into something other than a single-byte store instruction, or reorder it with surrounding code in unexpected ways.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/71867102/634919 for a few related examples.

Comment: @NateEldredge I'm aware. That's why I scoped it down to only the hardware level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No mainstream CPU ISAs do hardware race detection, so it's safe in asm.
Atomic stores (not [RMWs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39393850/is-incrementing-an-int-effectively-atomic-in-specific-cases) like CAS or `++atomic_var`) use the same asm instructions as normal stores.

**Cache is coherent on all CPU ISAs** (not necessarily GPUs), at least between cores that we run threads across, which is why C / C++ `volatile` works similar to `atomic<T>` with `memory_order_relaxed`, on normal compilers that treat `volatile` accesses as requiring a load or store in the asm. (*[When to use volatile with multi threading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4557979/when-to-use-volatile-with-multi-threading/58535118#58535118)* - never, except in Linux kernel code which rolls its own atomics with inline asm for ordering and GNU C semantics for `volatile` which include doing the load or store with a single instruction if possible.)

So for a CPU core to commit a store from its private store buffer into coherent L1d cache, it needs to get MESI Exclusive ownership of the cache line it's storing into *before* it can commit.  In C++ terms, this is why a "modification order" exists for all `atomic` variables.  In asm, such an order exists for every cache line.

If you had an ARM board with a microcontroller + DSP with non-coherent shared memory, you could still have both cores store to the same address without anything going wrong, other than getting potentially surprising values if you ever read that shared memory region.  e.g. a core with cache would probably see the value it last stored, even if the other core had done a later store.

---

**In high-level languages**, it's generally not safe to assume that your code using non-atomic assignments compiles to equivalent asm to `atomic` with `relaxed`, unless you use something like C `volatile` on mainstream compilers that handle it the way you'd expect.

On a C implementation like `clang -fsanitize=thread`, it may abort or print extra stuff to `stderr` when two threads concurrently write the same non-atomic `int *`.

I don't know what you're talking about with `write` system calls; that seems very distantly related to asm stores, and the kernel will need to implement POSIX semantics for `write` atomicity (atomic update of the file-position and the I/O, in case multiple processes or threads are sharing the same open file descriptor.)  See https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html#BUGS for some mention of that, e.g. Linux 3.14 and later implement this correctly.

TLBs aren't relevant here.

Comment: To be clear, the POSIX `write` part is just the byte copy from the socket buffer to my read buffer. It's very indirectly related, but relevant in that the (kernel) machine code executed is relevant. Your answer does answer my question, though.

Comment: I do plan to wait a bit for other answers to potentially fill in, before I mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: @Claudia: `write` copies *from* user-space to the kernel's buffers.  Perhaps you meant `read`?

Comment: Yeah, I meant `read`. My bad.

Comment: @Claudia: Ok, so simultaneous reads (maybe from different threads) to the same buffer?  Safe in practice, and I'd assume Linux's `copy_to_user` doesn't do any locking, but contention via cache coherency could still hurt performance if it's actually common to do this. Might be more efficient to avoid false-sharing with separate buffers for each thread, like a 4K or 1536 byte buffer.  Or with `readv` to recycle the same small (1K or 4K) thread-private buffer multiple times so the kernel gets L1d cache hits even for a larger read.  Or perhaps `sendfile` to an fd open on `/dev/null`.